# How to store only images excluding nodata area in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Using ' Raster -> Extract -> Raster Cut ' in QGIS and 'Nodata = 0', I cut the black part of the Landsat8 image as shown below.

[image]
[image]

However, when I saved it as "tif file", it seems that the black area is still there.

So I tried to put the tif file in Google Earth, and it appeared as shown below.

[image]
[image]

I want to save and show only the image that I cut. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Images are rectilinear. You can't not store the parts of the image you don't want to keep, but you can render them so the collar is not visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21577/vince)'s comment suggests, the best way is to make the `Nodata` values transparent. If you can't do that, you may try the following:

1. You can cut out a part of the image from the full scene (in this case you will lose some of the image pixels that are not equal to `Nodata`).
2. You can pick up such a projection so that the image is no longer rotated, then save the image (in practice, picking up such a projection is difficult or almost impossible).
3. In any raster editor rotate the image and crop the black borders (the geographical reference will be lost).